# Regex substitution: what is the difference between $& and Value (in lambda expression)?

Tags: c#, regex

Say I want to use a regular expression to add "test" before each word in a string.

```
string MyText="hello world"
string Pattern = "\w+";
```

I could do this:

```
Regex.Replace(MyText, Pattern, "test$&")
```

or this:

```
Regex.Replace(MyText, Pattern, m=>"test"+m.Value)
```

I would get the same result so what's the difference between $& and Value in the lambda expression? If there's not difference in terms of results, is there a performance issue?

Comment: +1; I didn't know you could use a lambda here.

Answer (score 1):

Lambdas are anonymous methods which work just the same as regular ones. The one declared in your example is equivalent to: 
        `string Convert(RegexMatch match) { return "test" + match.Value; }`. 
Using this syntax can give you access to a much richer range of possibilities then using the Regex expression used in your first example.

Comment: The question is not "what is a lambda expression"... What I would like to know is if there are any differences between using "test$&" and m=>"test"+m.Value I don't think there are functional differences between the 2 but I'm not sure at 100%. I would also like to know the performance issue of using 1 solution over the other one.